# Python Request JSON

Tags: python, json, types

I would like to check each JSON content type with my expectation type. I receive JSON in my python code like this:

```
a = request.json['a']
b = request.json['b']
```

when I checked a and b type, it is always return Unicode. I checked it like this:

```
type(a)  # or
type(b)  # (always return: type 'unicode')
```

How do I check if `request.json['a']` is `str`, if `request.json['a']` is always `unicode`?

Comment: Unicode is a string encoding, so a type of `unicode` seems like it's probably a `str`. If it looks like a `str` and quacks like a `str` then it must be a `str`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are on Python 2.x and not Python 3 (because in Python 3 both `type('a')` and `type(u'a')` are `str`, not `unicode`)

So in Python 2, what you should know is `str` and `unicode` both are subclasses of `basestring` so instead of testing with

```
if isinstance(x, (str, unicode)): # equiv. to type(x) is str or type(x) is unicode
   # something
```

you can do (Python 2.x)

```
if isinstance(x, basestring):
   # do something
```

In Python 3 you don't have to distinguish between `str` and `unicode`, just use

```
if isinstance(x, str):
   # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of built-in sequence types in python, `str` is one of them, and `Unicode str` is another.

So technically no, it's not a `str`, it's a `Unicode str`, but you may as well just treat it like a `str`.

Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Python 2.x`,:

```
isinstance(a, basestring)
```

Or if you are using `Python 3.X`:

```
isinstance(a, str)
```